# jQuery click function -- selector's css not being changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm going nuts over an issue I'm sure is obvious to someone.

I want a certain section of my page to disappear when a button is clicked.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.page-section').css('display', 'none');
   });
});
```

The script is being referenced correctly. jQuery is being loaded first. If I put an alert('something') inside the click event, it fires.

But for some reason, I am unable to get the css to change.

When I use the same line of code in my console, the css changes as it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the class `.page-section` is the correct one

Comment: to hide the element instead of calling `css()` you can use `$('.page-section').hide()`

Comment: @codehorse it allows any valid css property value can be assigned using `.css()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I just checked. It is the correct class. And I tried .hide(), but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Skitterm that simply means the element `$('.page-section')` does not exists... can you add `alert($('.page-section').length)` and see what is alerted

Comment: @Skitterm also it will be better if you can give some context about where it is called

Comment: what element it is? can you paste your html? is there more javascript code loaded?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I get 1 back, which means it's there. I also logged the element to the console and got back what I should.

Comment: @Skitterm then some other style is interfering with this...

Comment: can you inspect the element using browser element inspector and see the styles assigned

Comment: I set a break point; it is applying the style change, but once it leaves the function, the change doesn't persist.

Comment: try in other browser.. maybe some firebug etc. is somehow affecting that..

Comment: @Skitterm that means some other script is doing it

Comment: @Skitterm for checking purpose do you mind changing the class to `page-section1` and then set the display using `$('.page-section1').hide()`

Comment: @Skitterm also whether `.button` is causing a page reload

Comment: @ArunPJohny: hide() hides the page while I'm still in the method, but as soon as I leave the method, the effects are null. Perhaps it is something with having it nested in document.ready, but I can't see how.

Comment: @Skitterm my assumption is some other script is changing the visibility back... that is why I asked you to change the class name and check

Comment: Possible to provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @Fresher: While putting the code in a jsfiddle, everything worked fine. I think it has to do with my js files loading in as MIME type text/plain for some reason. These files are all on my machine as files, not hosted from a server. That may contribute to the problem.

Comment: @Skitterm Is there any way you could upload these to a staging page? Also, something else to check: what if you add an event argument to your handler function and add `e.preventDefault(); return false;` to the end? (If the element is a link or a button in a form, it could be causing the page to reload.)

Answer (score 1):

Try replace this:

```
 $('.page-section').css('display', 'none');
```

with this:

```
 $('.page-section').css({'display':'none'});
```

or

```
 $('.page-section').hide();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like it should work.  Have you inspected that element with developer tools after clicking the button?  You should be able to see what classes are being applied, even if another style is overriding it, for example, if you had .page-section{display:block !important;} somewhere in your stylesheet, your jQuery wouldn't hide it.  It also seems possible that that element is actually being hidden, but it's actually some other element you're trying to hide.